# What is the term for person that cannot be honest with themselves and fakes happiness

Tags: word-request

What is term for an emotionally void person who cannot be honest with themselves and fakes their own happiness? They obsess about a childhood that was terrible but they make it into a fantasy.

Comment: Would you provide more context please? It seems like you're asking about a very specific person, and it's difficult to come up with a single general term. What is the characteristic that you want to emphasize? That they are deluded about having a good childhood? That they are giving the appearance of having a perfect life in public even though their private life is dysfunctional?

Answer (score 2):

Such persons are said to be "in denial".

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for expressions like:

1) [**fantasy world**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fantasy+world)  something existing solely in the imagination.

2) [**fool's paradise**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fool%27s+paradise)  a state of being happy for foolish or unfounded reasons.

3) [**through rose-colored glasses**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/through+rose-colored+glasses) With an unduly cheerful, optimistic, or favorable view of things

So, you can say for example, "xyz person lives in a fantasy world"

Comment: Those aren't descriptions of a person though.

Comment: @ColleenV I see. I edited my answer by adding a sentence that the OP can choose to make about a person.